# Excel - copy values from one column to another

Tags: excel, excel-formula, lookup

I have 2 columns in my excelsheet:

[image]

I have another 2 columns in the same excelsheet:

[image]

I want to fill the second table (first screenshot) with values from the second screenshot (second column) and join by the first column (values like AA.....). How to do that? One value, for example AA14425088 occurs 2 times so in my second column in first screenshot have to be 2 values (separated by comma ",") like:

Comment: do you try VBA?

Comment: No, I want to use excel formulas like LOOKUP etc.

Comment: or something else to properly copy values...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build up the desired string in the second screenshot by adding another column that concatenates the strings (bottom-up) in the second column if the strings in the first column match:

C1:

```
=IF(A2=A1,B1&","&C2,B1)
```

Then `VLOOKUP()` on that

Comment: ok so in my first screenshot we have columns A, B. The second screenshot: columns C,D. So how I have to use your function now?

Comment: Modify the columns as per this new information. I naturally called the first column of the second screen shot "A", so you'll want to replace "A" with "C". Similarly B->D and C->E

Comment: Directly. `=VLOOKUP(A1,C:E,3,FALSE)`

Comment: NOw I have: in 1 column (A) document code (like AA14424107), second column (B) is empty (has to be filled with merged values using your IF function), and C column has merged by comma "," values. Where to use VLOOKUP?

Comment: You mean Column E has the merged column values. C has the lookup values and D has the original values. So then B has the `=VLOOKUP(A1,C:E,3,FALSE)` formula.

Comment: YOU ARE MY MASTER! Thanks!